# Run pynput lib example program on raspberrypi(ubuntu18.04)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

example program :
https://pypi.org/project/pynput/
The part called 'Monitoring the mouse '

Actually I tried all the examples,but none can run successful

This is report error ↓:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 193, in run
    self._run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 385, in _run
    self._context = dm.record_create_context(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 227, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: record_create_context
```

Comment: But when I run it on my computer, there is no such problems...

Comment: Is that perhaps because the error message  you present is from Python 2 but on your our computer you are running Python 3?

Comment: My raspberrypi has both Python2 and Python3, and my computer too, I have tried $python mouse.py and $python3 mouse.py on my raspberrypi but none works. I also tried on my computer, both are OK

Answer (score 0):

That's because I use VNC to remote control my raspberrypi, when I tried to connect screen, keyboard and mouse to my raspberrypi, it works！
Thank you all！